# R programming : select element from split string based on value in another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame having one column of words, with syllables separated by hyphens.  I want to extract the nth syllable, where n is given in another column.  Like this:

```
word <- c("to-ma-to", "cheese", "ta-co")
whichSyl <- c(2, 1, 1)
mydf <- data.frame(word, whichSyl)
mydf$word <- as.character(mydf$word)
```

desired: a vector containing

```
ma
cheese
ta
```

If this were, say, awk, I would just do

```
'{split($1,a,"-"); print a[$2]}'
```

The words don't always have the same number of syllables.

It seems likely that there is a straightforward way to do this, but I'm not seeing it.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapply` and `strsplit` to get,

```
mapply('[', strsplit(mydf$word, '-'), whichSyl)
#[1] "ma"     "cheese" "ta"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I wrote a function that does one row at a time, and then uses `lapply()` to iterate over all rows and `do.call(rbind())` to bind all of those responses together.

```
getSyl <- function(i){
  strsplit(mydf$word[i], '-')[[1]][mydf$whichSyl[i]]
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(mydf), getSyl))


     [,1]    
[1,] "ma"    
[2,] "cheese"
[3,] "ta"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` and row/column indexing

```
read.table(text=mydf$word, sep="-", header=FALSE,
                fill=TRUE)[cbind(1:nrow(mydf), mydf$whichSyl)]
#[1] "ma"     "cheese" "ta"
```